# Python/Django 2.0/Bootstrap3: Retrieving data from db based on form inputs using Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python. So I need help on an issue. I have checked StackOverflow for finding similar problems, but could not solve the problem yet.
I am creating a web app on django and there I want to retrieve the tours from the db based on the criteria accepted from a form. But it is not working.
 Here is what I did:

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from django.urls import reverse

    class Tour(models.Model):
        TourOperator = models.ForeignKey(TourOperator, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        TourCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, help_text='Ex. JT001 ') 
        Title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Title of the tour here")
        Slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
        Type = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices = TOUR_TYPES, help_text="Select from the list")
        Duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        ShortDesc = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Short description in 200')
        Description = models.TextField(help_text='Description of the tour...')
        Itinerary = models.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Itinerary of the tour...")
        Inclusions = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Inclusions of the tour; Seperate them with commas")
        Exclusions = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Exclusions of the tour; Seperate them with commas")
        Difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Enter a value between 1 to 10")
        GroupSize = models.CharField(max_length=2, help_text="Group size")
        Seasonality = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Seasonality of the tour; Ex. July - September")
        Highlights = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Highlights of the tour; Ex. Yamchun fortress, etc")
        #Destination_id = models.ForeignKey(Destination)
        Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
        Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='tours_image/')
        Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        Available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        Rating = models.IntegerField()
        StartDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        EndDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from tours.models import Tour

class SearchTourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tour
        # fields = ('Type','Destination', 'StartDate', 'Available') #Country
        exclude = ('Exclusions', )
```

search_tour.html

```
          <!-- Form  -->

        <form action="" method="GET">

            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="activities">Country</label>
                    <select  id="activities" class="form-control">
                        <!-- name="Country" -->
                        <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="activities">Type of tours/Activities</label>
                    <select name="Type" value="{{ tour.Type }} id="activities" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">All tours/activities</option>
                        <option value="Trekking">Trekking</option>
                        <option value="Hiking">Hiking</option>
                        <option value="Jeep-tour">Jeep-tour</option>
                        <option value="Cross-border tour">Cross-border tour</option>
                        <option value="City tour tour">City tour tour</option>
                        <option value="Sightseeing">Sightseeing</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="destination">Destination</label>
                    <select name="Destination" id="destination" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">All destinations</option>
                        <option value="Bartang">Bartang</option>
                        <option value="Sarez lake">Sarez lake</option>
                        <option value="Murghab">Murghab</option>
                        <option value="Fedchenko">Fedchenko</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="date-start">Date Travel</label>
                    <input name="StartDate" type="text" id="date-start" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Search">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    <!-- Form  /-->
    {% block content_main %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center gtco-heading">
        <h2>Search Result</h2>
        <p>Here is what matched your query.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <!-- Tour viewer -->
    {% for tour in tours %}
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="dtpTCard">
          <figure>
              <img src="{{ tour.Image.url }}" alt="{{ tour.Title }}" class="img-responsive" style="width:400px; height:230px;">
          </figure>
          <div>
            <!-- <a href=""> -->
              <h2 class="dtpCardTitleTextColor"> {{ destination.Region | truncatewords:1 }} Bartang, Tajikistan  {{ destination.Country | truncatewords:1 }} </h2>
            <!-- </a> -->
            <!-- <p>Bartang valley is the remote area in Pamir, Tajikistan.
            </p> -->
            <div class="row dtpCardInRow">
              <!-- style="font-size: 14px;  color:#000000;" -->
              <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <b><u>Description</u></b>: {{ tour.ShortDesc|truncatechars:80  }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <b><u>Tour type</u></b>: {{ tour.Type | capfirst}}  <br>
                <b><u>Duration</u></b>: {{ tour.Duration }} days
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 dtpCardRight" >
                <b><u>Difficulty</u></b>: {{ tour.Difficulty }}/10<br>
                <b><u>Price</u></b>: ${{ tour.Price }}
              </div>
            </div>
              <br>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{tour.get_absolute_url }}">View tour</a>
            <!-- /tours/details/{{tour.id }} -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% empty %}
        <h4>Sorry, no items in this page.</h4>
        <p>Coming soon...</p>
      {% endfor %}
    <!-- Tour /-->
    </div>
    <!-- Pagination -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="font-size: 18px; ">
          <br>
          <div class="pagination">
              <span class="step-links">
                  {% if tours.has_previous %}
                      <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
                      <a href="?page={{ tours.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                  {% endif %}
                  <span class="current">
                      Page {{ tours.number }} of {{ tours.paginator.num_pages }}.
                  </span>
                  {% if tours.has_next %}
                      <a href="?page={{ tours.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                      <a href="?page={{ tours.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
                  {% endif %}
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Pagination /-->
    {% endblock content_main %}
```

vews.py

```
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
    from tours.forms import CreateTourForm, SearchTourForm
    from tours.models import Tour, Destination#, TourOperator
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.db.models import Q
    from django.conf import settings


    def search_tours(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = SearchTourForm(request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                Country = form.cleaned_data['Country']
                Type = form.cleaned_data['Type']
                Destination = form.cleaned_data['Destination']
                StartDate = form.cleaned_data['StartDate']

                tours = Tour.objects.filter(Q(Country__icontains = Country)|
                                    Q(Type__exact = int(Type))|
                                    Q(Destination__exact = int(Destination))|
                                    Q(StartDate__gte = int(StartDate)))

                return render(request, 'tours/search_tours.html', {
                    'tours': tours,
                    'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL,
                    'form':form,
                })

        else:
            form = SearchTourForm()

        tours = Tour.objects.filter(Available = True)


        return render(request, 'tours/search_tours.html', {
            'tours': tours,
            # 'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL,
            'form':form,
        })
```

url.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views
    from tours.views import ToursView

    app_name = 'tours'

    urlpatterns = [

        url(r'^$', ToursView.as_view(), name='tours'),
        url(r'^search/$', views.search_tours),
    ];
```

[image]

So the problem is that when I search, it outputs all the tours and ignores the form crieria. I am a beginner and could not figure out what is the issue ((

Links to the above files in GitHub:
[Django web app](https://github.com/Saidmamad/project)

Answer (score 1):

That form will almost certainly never be valid. Your model defines a whole set of fields, most of which are required, and your form doesn't exclude them so they will continue to be required. You don't output the form errors in the template, or repopulate it when it's invalid, so the user never sees that it is invalid.

But you really don't want a modelform here, just a standard form with the four fields you need explicitly declared. Model forms are for editing and creating model instances, which you're not doing.

Also note, the method will always be GET, since that is the standard request. Instead of checking for that, you should probably check that the GET contains data:

```
if request.GET:
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Daniel. So, I should change my form.py like below:
class SearchTourForm(forms.Form):
    Country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),required=True)
    Type = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Type of tour'}))
    Destination = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    StartDate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control'}))

Could you please help me what the problem now is with the search_tours func?

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed the form.Model to normal HTML form:

```
        <form name="SearchTour" action="" method="GET">
      <!-- {% csrf_token %}  needed? -->
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="Country">Country</label>
                <input id="Country" class="form-control" type="text" name="Country" placeholder="Country ..." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="TourType">Type of tours/Activities</label>
                <input type="text" name="Type" id="TourType" class="form-control"  >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="destination">Destination</label>
                <input type="text" name="Destination" id="destination" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="StartDate">Date Travel</label>
                <input name="StartDate" type="text" id="StartDate" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Search">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And here is my form.py

```
                class SearchTourForm(forms.Form):
                Country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),required=True)
                Type = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Type of tour'}))
                Destination = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
                StartDate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control'}))
```

And here is my view function for that, which might be the main problem:

```
                def search_tours(request):
                if request.method == 'GET':
                    form = SearchTourForm(request.GET)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        Country = form.cleaned_data['Country']
                        Type = form.cleaned_data['Type']
                        Destination = form.cleaned_data['Destination']
                        StartDate = form.cleaned_data['StartDate']

                        tours = Tour.objects.filter(Q(Country__icontains = Country)|
                                            Q(Type__icontains = Type)|
                                            Q(Destination__icontains = Destination)|
                                            Q(StartDate__gte = StartDate))

                        return render(request, 'tours/search_tours.html', {
                            'tours': tours,
                            'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL,
                            'form':form,
                        })
                else:
                    form = SearchTourForm()

                tours = Tour.objects.filter(Available = True)
                return render(request, 'tours/search_tours.html', {
                    'tours': tours,
                    'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL,
                    'form':form,
                })
```

STILL NOT WORKING! What might be the problem?